# Total Differentials Fluid Mechanics

Tags: partial-derivative

I'm having trouble with total differentials in relation to the attached picture (fluid deformation). I don't understand how the expressions for du and dv come about.

It looks like u = f(x) and v = f(y), so i'm not sure why the incremental increases du and dv involve partial differentials, rather than differentials of only one variable. [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0gj1.jpg)

It's probably pretty obvious to someone in the know, all help gratefully received

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

In general you have $u = u(x,y)$ so that

$$
{\rm d}u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}{\rm d}x + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}{\rm d}y
$$

However, if you move vertically in your diagram ${\rm d}y = 0$, so that this becomes

$$
u + {\rm d}u = u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}{\rm d}x
$$

with a similar expression for $v = v(x,y)$